# What logo we can have ? Let's start working

Tags: discussion

as a nascent community, we like to grow as well as have an identity. A Logo carry a lot about the identity.

We should start think, brew, and sketch the ideas. Even you can contribute your not-so-polished design.

IMO, A logo should be simple, unique, meaningful and fun. What do you think ?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote's motive ... :/

Comment: The downvote was likely because we won't get a logo for a long while...the logo won't come until graduation, and that likely won't happen for [at least two years](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239464/266359).

Comment: thanks a lot @Shokhet, that makes sense

Comment: See also post-graduation [coffee.se] site ideas in [this later meta question](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/q/86/262).

Answer (score 7):

A coffee bean. This was basically the idea i had in mind when i made the proposal to begin with. Everything we talk about is based on the coffee bean.

Answer (score 2):

A cup of coffee with answers and questions coming out of the top of the cup like steam. I think it is very coffee related and original!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of discussion, how about a variation on the icon from Ron Cobb?

The icon I refer to can be seen in... Alien from Ridley Scott. Cobb designed the "Semiotic Standard For All Commercial Trans-Stellar Utility Lifter And Heavy Element Transport Spacecraft". One of the icons is a simple, straight coffee cup. You can see it on a [reproduction by a software company](http://design.iconfactory.com/ios-7-and-alien/) (see around the middle of the page).

The idea here is that this is very nerdy.

---

On a side note, an icon like that one could be for the chat room.