# What should the design for our site look like?

Tags: discussion

Here at Coffee Stack Exchange, we reached public beta about three days ago! This is exciting as we're slowly moving towards being a non-beta site! Graduated Stack Exchange sites have their own themes, including different icons for stuff like badges. Let's start thinking about what we'd like our site to look like: please answer this question with ideas about stuff like badge icons, downvote/upvote buttons, color themes, even the background! All ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Anyone can answer. Don't be shy!

Comment: Coffee won't get its very own design until it [graduates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), but that's no reason not to dream about what it could look like. Carry on :)

Comment: This is like the preview for when Coffee graduates. Seeing how two users already got 1.2k in 16 days, we should be fine.

Comment: See also [this previous meta-question about a logo](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/q/28/262), which might also be useful for pre-graduation community promotion.

Answer (score 1):

## Badge Icons

My recommendation is that instead of the plain colored circles, there should be coffee cups. This would work great since who doesn't want a cup of coffee? This is like awarding cups of coffee to people. :-)

## Downvote and Upvote Buttons

I would like to keep them just the way they are for some SE originality and it is easier to know what you are doing. If comfortable enough, there might be a green thumbs up for the upvote button and a red thumbs down for the downvote button.

## Word Color

I would like to be optional will variety of colors. I'm think of chocolate brown, black, brown, light brown, and all sorts of brown and coffee related colors!

## Background

Just like Area 51's alien themed background, I hope we have a coffee themed background. There would be coffee cups, coffee machines, coffee beans, steam, and a light brown paint underneath all the decorations.

## Other

Well I got nothing else. I hope this gets chosen for the new Coffee SE site stlye (if this question survives and there are multiple answers...)! Good Luck to future answers and consider the other [meta question](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/what-logo-we-can-have-lets-start-working?lq=1) about the logo!

Comment: Don't forget [logo](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/q/28/262)!

Comment: I would prefer an 8-bit coffee mug as the logo.

Comment: You could answer the question in the link the mod posted...

Comment: `body{background: #EDD4AC url(//cdn.sstatic.net/programmers/img/favicon.ico?v=8fef1c85f782) left top; }`
The trick is to, make another .png image and put the favicon in there, so that there's spacing (because most browsers do not support `space` yet).

Comment: I'd prefer to see coffee beans as badges and maybe the coffee-cup as a logo..